# What is the opening song of Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel, game-music-identification

In [the opening sequence of Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel while the bandits are hijacking a Hyperion rocket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zkn75vxbih0#t=1m55s), what is the song?  It's not on [the soundtrack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NW1VJP4).

Comment: Just to preempt things, it's not Darude-Sandstorm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be *Black Dragon* by *The Vines*.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it, I heard it as "take a ride on the *flying tiger*".  Thanks!  And the following song is *Goodbye* also by *The Vines*.